# Не загружается картинка в imageView

Tags: android, listview, java

В потоке загружаю картинку, и возвращаю ее. Картинку поток загружает, проверено.

```
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try {
return Drawable.createFromStream(
(InputStream)new URL(objects[0].toString()).getContent(),
 "src");
            } catch (IOException e) {}       
            return null;
        }
```

А вот тут, получаемый рисунок уже null,

```
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> loadMyItems() {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            try {
  !!!             **map.put("photo", ATK.execute("http://kocha.co/ziFzx").get());**
  !!!              Log.d(q,"MAP="+map.toString());//Тут уже photo=null
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            };
            arrayList.add(map);
            return arrayList;
        }
```

Comment: Вы синхронно добавляете объект из асинхронного запроса?

Судя по doInBackground, у вас AsyncTask юзается. Поэтому обрабатывать результат запроса надо в onPostExecute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может надо вместо

```
map.toString()
```

использовать

```
map.get("photo").toString()
```

Вы ведь хотите вытащить значение, ключ которого photo?